# the physical path for my files inside the Resources folder of XCode (for IOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, filepath

I'm developing an application for iPad. I want to access a text file inside the Resources folder! I'm doing that in following way:

```
 NSString* filePath = @"/Users/net4uonline/Desktop/slots2/paylines.txt";
```

Now, if I move my whole project from Desktop to somewhere else I know this won't work. So, is there any way to give a relative path for this file instead of the current path. Maybe like the following?

```
NSString* filePath = @"Resources/paylines.txt";
```

I know this won't work but as my file is always going to reside inside the Resources folder, so I thought this might work!

Comment: are u making an ios app or a mac app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are looking for [NSBundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and **pathForResource:ofType:** method, aren't you?

Comment: is it even available for ios??

Comment: According to the documentation, it's available for iOS.